# HTML | Center menubar on screen

Tags: html, css, position, center

need some help. I'm just learning HTML and have been looking at how to do menus today, whilst doing so I have ran into a problem.

I can't seem to figure out how to center the menu on screen.

This is what I have so far;

```
<div id="navMenu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>

        <li><a href="#">WWW.</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Through the years</a></li>
        </ul></li>

        <li><a href="#">Browsers</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">IE</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Firefox</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Chrome</a></li>
        </ul></li>

        <li><a href="#">CSS</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">CSS 2.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">CSS 3</a></li>
        </ul></li>

        <li><a href="#">Scripting</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">JavaScripts</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">jQuery</a></li>
        </ul></li>

    </ul>
</div>
```

Current CSS;

```
#navMenu{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#navMenu ul{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    line-height:30px;
}
#navMenu li{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
    float: left;
    position: relative;

    background-color: #999;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
#navMenu ul li a{
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration:none;
    height:30px;
    width:150px;
    display:block;
    color: #FFF;
    border: 1px solid #FFF;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
}
#navMenu ul ul{
    position:absolute;
    visibility:hidden;
    top:32px;
}
#navMenu ul li:hover ul{
    visibility:visible;
}
#navMenu li:hover{
    background-color: #09F;
}
#navMenu ul li:hover ul li a:hover{
    background-color: #CCC;
    color: #000;
}
#navMenu a:hover{
    color:#000;
}
```

The above produces this .... http://gyazo.com/55cf62d121ef16eb1248e5246d0accae

Anyway to get the menu bar in the center of the screen.

SIDE NOTE:: Any spoilers tags on this site?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=center+menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `display: inline-block` and `text-align: center`.

Set `display: inline-block` for the `<ul>` and `text-align: center` for the container `#navMenu`. Set `text-align: left` for `#navMenu li` to fix the submenus.

Also

**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/borglinm/HG33e/2/)**

```
#navMenu{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    text-align: center;
}
#navMenu ul{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    line-height:30px;
    display: inline-block;
}
#navMenu li{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    text-align: left;
    float: left;
    list-style:none;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #999;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Comment: That works, well sort of it then messes up the sub menus. http://gyazo.com/f4e606032eca49eacd0fa193fb93c8ab. Managed to fixed it thanks. :) http://gyazo.com/46e18486eca6747527506937aebaded5

Answer (score 0):

Add a width to your menu wrapper and give the left and right an automatic margin.
You can adjust the width depending on where in the center you want to have your nav positioned.

```
#navMenu {
width: 960px;
margin:0 auto;
padding:0;
text-align: center;
```

}

The margin and paddings your have in the ul and li are not needed.

```
#navMenu ul{
list-style: none;
line-height:30px;
display: inline-block;
text-align: center;
```

}

```
#navMenu li{
display: inline;
```

}

Padding should go here to keep all your links even.

```
  #navMenu li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
```

}